# $_SESSION Variables empty at XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

After the hoster upgraded from PHP 4.x to PHP 5.4.1 a friend of mine has a huge problem accessing $_SESSION variables when doing it via XMLHttpRequest (he uses jQuery for that).

I hope the following snippets of his code are illustrating his problem:

index.php

```
<?PHP
    session_start ();
    $_SESSION['chatfenster'] = array();
    $_SESSION['user'] = 1;
?>
<!-- HTML Markup -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.post("http://www.his-domain.at/ticker_tracker.php", function( feedback ) { alert(feedback); } ) 
        },
        10000);
    });
```

ticker_tracker.php:

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

When he browses to index.php and afterwards manually to ticker_tracker.php, the $_SESSION variables are var_dumped correctly, but if the php file is called via $.post(), the $_SESSION variables are all empty, thus alerting just "array{}".

Hosters support says everything is fine and they didn't change any settings at all, but I noticed that Chrome blocks the XMLHttpRequest due to cross domain requests, giving the error message (also only appearing after upgrade to PHP 5.4.1):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present.
```

Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers on the very top of every php solves this error, but the main problem (empty $_SESSION variables) still remains.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: lol... if your friend can't use this website then you are his good friend!

Comment: not quite sure if I understand your comment... the code was working until the hoster changed the php version. He didn't change the code at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the access-control-allow-origin error (that can be solved as you said by adding a header), then you are doing a cross-domain request. That's why you have different session contents: they are different sessions!

This can be from one machine (domain) to the other (www.one.com to www.two.com), this could be from one subdomain to the other (www.one.com vs one.com) or this could be a different service (e.g. http vs https, and these might be served by a different machine or process).

All these things have one thing in common: you have a request that seems to go to a different place (hence the allow origin). And a different place has different sessions, as they are not shared.

Check why you have the access control thingy going on: the request isn't going to the same place. So 'fixing' it with headers is just a fix for the origin: remove that 'fix', and make the request not needing it. then you're back at the same server/process/whatever, and will have the same session.

Comment: Seems like there was a problem with the absolute path within the $.post(). Although the URLs were exactly the same, it started working again, after we replaced the absolute paths with relative ones.